# Changing font colour according to the data output

Tags: php, html

I have a data table to show on the table one row is called "address". There are only two types of address can be output "dhaka" and "yaka" . I want to show the font colour as red when the output is "dhaka" and green when the output is "yaka".

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Dashboard</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    .wrapper{
        width: 650px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .page-header h2{
        margin-top: 0;
    }
    
    table tr td:last-child a{
        margin-right: 15px;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
    });
</script>
</head>
 <body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                
                <?php
                
                require_once "config.php";
                
                
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM student_record";
                if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
                    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                        echo "<table class='table table-bordered table-striped table-hover '>";
                            echo "<thead>";
                                echo "<tr>";
                                    echo "<th>#</th>";
                                    echo "<th>Name</th>";
                                    echo "<th>Address</th>";
                                    echo "<th>Marks</th>";
                                    echo "<th>Action</th>";
                                echo "</tr>";
                            echo "</thead>";
                            echo "<tbody>";
                            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                                echo "<tr>";
                                    echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td>" . $row['address'] . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td>" . $row['marks'] . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td>";
                                        echo "<a href='read.php?id=". $row['id'] ."' title='View 
 Record' data-toggle='tooltip'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open'></span></a>";
                                        echo "<a href='update.php?id=". $row['id'] ."' title='Update 
 Record' data-toggle='tooltip'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></a>";
                                        echo "<a href='delete.php?id=". $row['id'] ."' title='Delete 
 Record' data-toggle='tooltip'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></a>";
                                    echo "</td>";
                                echo "</tr>";
                            }
                            echo "</tbody>";                            
                        echo "</table>";
                        
                        mysqli_free_result($result);
                    } else{
                        echo "<p class='lead'><em>No records were found.</em></p>";
                    }
                } else{
                    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($conn);
                }
                
                
                mysqli_close($conn);
                ?>
                <form  method="post" action="search1.php?go"  id="searchform"> 
                    <input  type="text" name="name"> 
                    <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Search"> 
                </form> 
                
            </div>
        </div>        
    </div>
  </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to actually use if elseif statements:-

```
<?php

if ($row['address'] == 'dhaka') {
    $color = 'RED';
} elseif ($row['address'] == 'yaka') {
    $color = 'GREEN';
}

echo "<td><span style=\"color: $color\">" . $row['address'] . "</span></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to include this code inside while loop

```
if($row['address'] =='dhaka'){$color='red';}
else{$color='green';}
```

And update the address line with

```
echo "<td style='color:'.$color.'>" . $row['address'] . "</td>";
```